# How can get the ios version from ionic app

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I finished my ionic app, I'm working on windows, i also managed to get the apk file and the application works as expected, but i want to get ios vesion also to install it in Iphone  how can do that??

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/

You should be able to execute the below:

```
var currentPlatformVersion = ionic.Platform.version();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ionic 4 it's cordova-plugin-device.

```
import {Device} from '@ionic-native/device/ngx';
...
constructor(private device: Device) {
    console.log(this.device.version); //'13.1.2'
}
```